# innacessible cardinal as a model of $V_\kappa$

Tags: cardinals

Why  $V_\kappa$  satisfies the replacement axiom so that it is a model of ZFC
for any inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$
**EDIT**

[Regular cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_cardinal)
Replacement
if $F$ is a class function then for any set $X$
there exists a set $Y=F(X)=\{F(x)|x\in X\}$

Comment: What have you learned? Do you know the definition of an inaccessible ordinal/cardinal? Do you know what the replacement axiom is?

Comment: You need to include these details so that we can provide better-aimed answers.

Comment: @Trebor I have provided them in my OQ. Any help now?